# Is it correct to do Response.Write in a finally block?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In asp.net -
I have code that sends a Json-serialized-object in the http response in a finally block - but the requesting client does not receive anything in the response.

(I checked to make sure the object is not null when it is sent in debugging.)

Is it possible that sending a response from a finally block would cause this problem?

Answer (score 1):

No, using code inside `finally` block can not cause problems by itself.

There is something wrong with code execution flow.

Answer (score 0):

No its good place to write such type of code in Finally block..which always execute.